# How do you stop using "you" in every question?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I post questions on stackexchange sites and I'd like them to sound more professional.

However, they usually start like this:

> How do you....

How can I make my questions sound more professional?

Is there a better way to think of the question or is there just something mechanical I need to do differently?

Comment: Well, I notice you didn't ask us *"How do you make your questions sound more professional?"*, so it seems to me you're already getting the hang of it. Or you could have asked *"How can questions be made to sound more professional?"*, for example. Whatever - there are so many alternatives I think it's just Not Constructive to ask for a list of possibilities to be posted as votable "answers".

Comment: "How does one ... (do this)?", "How is this done?", etc.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but not on-topic here. Writers says that the post is also off-topic there, since it is a request for asking what to write. Sorry.

Comment: Adding to what others said, I wonder what ever happened to the simple "how to".  It doesn't have to be you, me or one in the first place. No need for passive voice, either.

Comment: I tried that, but it sounded like a statement rather then a question....`How to bake cookies?` for example is ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 3):

> How do you…
>
> How would you…

Is fine for many contexts.

> How does one…
>
> How would one…

Is more formal and its precise meaning is closer to what you probably mean; you aren't asking how I or any other reader does something, you're asking how any person would, and so the indefinite personal pronoun *one* is appropriate.

However, some consider it stuffy. Also, if you aren't used to it, it can be easy to fall into hypercorrections where you use it where *you*, *I* or *they* are more appropriate.

> How can I…
>
> How could I…

You used it above, so it came naturally to you. It's what you really want to know with most SE questions; how *you* can do something. It works for both formal and informal registers, and so is appropriate for both professional and chatty cases, and SE which is a strange mixture of the two.

Comment: How are questions made to sound more professional?      Can a solid state drive suffer a head crash?

Comment: @WayfaringStranger It'd be harder to turn that second one into a form using *you* than it ever would to avoid *you*.